# faster way to add many large matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, sum, addition

Say I have many (around 1000) large matrices (about 1000 by 1000) and I want to add them together element-wise. The very naive way is using a temp variable and accumulates in a loop. For example,

```
summ=0;
for ii=1:20
    for jj=1:20
    summ=summ+ rand(400);
    end
end
```

After searching on the Internet for some while, someone said it's better to do with the help of sum(). For example,

```
sump=zeros(400,400,400);
count=0;
for ii=1:20
    for j=1:20
        count=count+1;
        sump(:,:,count)=rand(400);
    end
end
sum(sump,3);
```

However, after I tested two ways, the result is

```
Elapsed time is 0.780819 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.085279 seconds.
```

which means the second method is even worse.

So I am just wondering if there any effective way to do addition? Assume that I am working on a computer with very large memory and a GTX 1080 (CUDA might be helpful but I don't know whether it's worthy to do so since communication also takes time.)

Thanks for your time! Any reply will be highly appreciated!.

Comment: If you turn the `profiler` on, then you can see that the creation of _sump_ variable in the 2nd case takes most of the time. But once you have that matrix, then `sum(sump,3)` is quicker. However, in case-1, the program will take the same amount of time even if you have the ready-made 400x400x400 matrix. I would say, using the `sum()` will be the fastest.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The crucial point in my case is that I need to start from nothing, meaning that every single matrix (each page) needs to be generated. And then I sum up each element from different pages. So it's not the case that I have some data(matrices) beforehand and simply sum(sump,3). Given this case, would you have any suggestion of which should be preferable?

Comment: If you will be generating these matrices, I’m sure adding them up will be a trivial cost compared to the generation. For example, profile your code, you’ll see `rand` is much more expensive than `+`. Just add them up as you generate them.

Comment: Your question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the crucial part of your problem? Data generation or just summing everything up? To solve the above problem the fastest way, `sum(rand(400,400,400),3)` should give you quite decent results.

Comment: Thanks for you help! This is much faster now by using sum(rand(400,400,400),3)

Comment: @Tik0, Thanks for your suggestion. This is much faster even when I use CUDA. By the way, it may not be a XY problem..It is just like what you think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastes way is to not use any loops in matlab at all.
In many cases, the internal functions of matlab all well optimized to use SIMD or other acceleration techniques. 
An example for using the build in functionalities to create matrices of the desired size is [`X = rand(sz1,...,szN)`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html).
In your explicit case `sum(rand(400,400,400),3)` should give you then the fastest result.